# Angular cli is throwing an error when I create a jQuery OpaqueToken.

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've included the jquery script file as a sependency in the scripts array in the angular-cli.json file.

```
"scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        ]
```

I created a simple service that exports a token for jquery.

```
import {OpaqueToken} from '@angular/core'

export let JQUERY_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('jQuery');
```

I imported the token and declared the jQuery object in my app.module.ts file,

```
import {JQUERY_TOKEN} from './shared/jquery'
declare let jQuery:any;
```

and also included the token in the providers array:

```
providers: [{provide:JQUERY_TOKEN, useValue: jQuery}]
```

When I run the "ng build" command, angular cli is throwing the following error:

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'jQuery'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 28:13 in the original .ts file), resolving
symbol AppModule in D:/public/src/app/app.module.ts

Could someone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, You haven't imported the right file

Instead of

```
import {JQUERY_TOKEN} from './shared/jquery'
```

try

```
import {JQUERY_TOKEN} from './shared/jquery.service'
```